# Way to use both cellular and Wifi network in android phone?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to write an app and I wish to enable and use both Wifi network and cellular network. Is there a particular way to do this.

Can someone point to some reference links of doing this.

I wish to do this simultaneously so that I can log cpu usage for my project.

Comment: You're saying you want to choose what requests are sent via WiFi vs cellular? I do not believe this is possible or advisable.

Comment: wish to enable and use both Wifi network ??-- if you mean turning them on, then i think not or shouldn't be able to cause that's a bit of a security risk. I wouldnt want an App turning my wifi on by itself.  what you can do is direct the user to the settings page to turn them on manually

Comment: Even I think that is not possible to do so... Just wanted to ask.

Comment: Well, a mobile hotspot on your Android uses both networks at the same time, and it routes traffic between the two networks.